# SQL film database queries

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I'm having trouble solving the following SQL requests:

1) "Give the original name and year, also the current name and year, and the studio of the films that were made before '1960' then remade after '2000'."

2) "Get the filmname of all films created before ‘1951’ and remade after ‘2000’"

There are several tables but I'm assuming that only 2 are needed: 'films' and 'remakes'

'films' attributes: filmid, filmname, year, director, studio

'remakes' attributes: filmid, title, year, priorfilm, prioryear

My understanding is that remakes are included in films so the priorfilm in 'remakes' table corresponds to a filmid in the 'films' table. I'm having trouble linking the two to be able to place the year conditions.

Comment: Show what you have tried already.

Comment: Looks like a homework question?

Comment: in my humble opinion... it doesn't matter if it is a homework or not. the purpose is to help and learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first query

```
SELECT f.filmname, f.year, f.studio, r.title, r.prioryear
       from film f , join remakes r on f.filmid = r.filmid
            where r.year > 2000 and f.year < 1960;
```

second query

```
select f.* from film f join remakes r on f.filmid = r.filmid
    where f.year < 1951 and r.year > 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join `films` (for the original) to `remakes` (which tells you how the films correspond) then to `films` again (for the remade versions).

**1:**

```
SELECT o.filmname as originalname, o.year as originalyear,
       c.filmname as remakename, c.year as remadeyear, o.studio
FROM films o
INNER JOIN remakes r on r.priorfilm = o.filmid
INNER JOIN films c on c.filmid = r.filmid
WHERE o.year < 1960 AND c.year > 2000
```

**2:**

```
SELECT o.filmname
FROM films o
INNER JOIN remakes r on r.priorfilm = o.filmid
INNER JOIN films c on c.filmid = r.filmid
WHERE o.year < 1951 AND c.year > 2000
```